# How to populate a list in excel using win32com module

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am trying to write lists into excel, the list contains a couple of columns.

I have included my code below. It seems to only extract the first value. I am fairly new to python, what am I missing?

**Code:**

```
import win32com.client as win32
#
Z = [3,4,6,8,9,11,40]
Q = ['x','y','z','e','g','AA','BB']

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets.Add()
ws.Name = "MyNewSheet"
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1),ws.Cells(1,2)).Value = ['Z','Q']
for i,e in enumerate (Z):
ws.Range("A2:A8").Value = [ i for i in (Z)]
for i,e in enumerate (Z):
ws.Range("B2:B8").Value = [ i for i in (Q)]
wb.SaveAs('beta.xlsx')
excel.Application.Quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that it wants to write the values as rows.  So, this re-aligns the writes to be by row:

**Code:**

```
import win32com.client as win32

Z = [3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 40]
Q = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'e', 'g', 'AA', 'BB']

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets.Add()
ws.Name = "MyNewSheet"
ws.Range("A1:B1").Value = ['Z', 'Q']
ws.Range("A2:B8").Value = list(zip(Z, Q))
wb.SaveAs('beta.xlsx')
excel.Application.Quit()
```

**Results:**

```
Z   Q
3   x
4   y
6   z
8   e
9   g
11  AA
40  BB
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.